# Yosemite does not have ftp sharing option in file sharing preferences?

Tags: macos, terminal, network, ftp

I have just obtained a Macbook Pro with Yosemite installed and am trying to connect to it from another host on the local network via ftp. The connection is refused. So I get into the preferences in the Yosemite system and look of ftp option in the file sharing preferences. There isn't one. There is options for afp, smb sharing but not ftp. On my other Macs there is an option for ftp sharing.

Also, when I set the ethernet interface to manual address with sub net mask, the settings are not installed as reflected in terminal app command ifconfig. I can use ifconfig to set it but the settings are dropped when the machine is rebooted. I have to set them every time the machine boots.

I could write a shell script to configure the interfaces but I don't know where to put this script so it will be run on startup.

does anyone have suggestions, useful info on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For the manual addressing, have you tried using the networksetup command? These settings can be set using the following command:

```
networksetup -setmanual <networkservice> <ip> <subnet> <router>
```

Comment: yes I used networksetup -setmanual <networkservice> <ip> <subnet> <router>
and it did not work for setting interface configuration at start up. I still
had to configure it manually via terminal with ifconfig.
I will ask a separate question regarding running shell scripts at startup.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the I need to use SFTP to connect. That is in the remote
login preferences of file sharing preferences.